# Where did the $-1$ come from?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, summation

It's a very specific question:

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+2} = \frac{x^2}{1-x}$

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+2)x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} = \frac{2x(1-x)+x^2}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{x(2-x)}{(1-x)^2}$$

Now,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac{x(2-x)}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{2}{x}\left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \color{Red}{- 1} \right] $$

Where is the $\color{Red}{-1}$ came from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index of the sum on the top is $n=1$ on the botton is $n=0$. The $-1$ cancels out the term $x^0$ in the last sum